# LINQ next/last date relative to today with EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following models:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstNameSurname { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RotaUser> RotaUser { get; set; }
}

public class RotaUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RotaId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Clinical { get; set; }
    public Rota Rota { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class Rota
{
    public int RotaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public int BankHolidays { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RotaUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I am summarizing this into a view model as below using LINQ with Entity Framework 6 for querying the database:

```
public class OnCallSummaryViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Next { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Last { get; set; }
    public int? Days { get; set; }
    public int? BankHolidays { get; set; }
}
```

Whilst the below works what I am doing to get the `Next` and `Last` values doesn't feel right and is returning the `MinDate` value of `01/01/0001` when I'd rather it return `NULL`

```
public ActionResult Summary()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var model = db.User
        .Include(u => u.RotaUser.Select(r => r.Rota))
        .Where(u => u.OnCall.Value)
        .GroupBy(u => new { u.UserId, u.FirstNameSurname })
        .Select(u => new OnCallSummaryViewModel
        {
            Name = u.Key.FirstNameSurname,
            Days = u.Sum(r => r.RotaUser.Sum(x => x.Rota.Days)),
            BankHolidays = u.Sum(r => r.RotaUser.Sum(x => x.Rota.BankHolidays)),
            Next = u.Min(ru => ru.RotaUser
                .Where(r => r.Rota.StartDate >= today)
                .Select(d => d.Rota.StartDate)
                .OrderBy(d => d)
                .FirstOrDefault()),
            Last = u.Max(ru => ru.RotaUser
                .Where(r => r.Rota.StartDate <= today)
                .Select(d => d.Rota.StartDate)
                .OrderBy(d => d)
                .FirstOrDefault()),
        })
        .ToList();

    return PartialView("Summary", model);
}
```

If I were to do this in TSQL the query I am looking to replicate would be as follows:

```
SELECT
    [User].UserId
,   [User].FirstNameSurname
,   SUM(Rota.[Days]) AS Days
,   SUM(Rota.BankHolidays) AS BankHolidays
,   MIN(CASE
        WHEN Rota.StartDate >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            THEN Rota.StartDate
    END) AS NEXT
,   MIN(CASE
        WHEN Rota.StartDate <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            THEN Rota.StartDate
    END) AS Last

FROM
    dbo.[User]
    LEFT JOIN OnCall.RotaUser
        ON  [User].UserId = RotaUser.UserId
    LEFT JOIN OnCall.Rota
        ON  RotaUser.RotaId = Rota.RotaId

WHERE
    [User].OnCall = 'TRUE'

GROUP BY
    [User].UserId
,   [User].FirstNameSurname
```

What is the correct way to retrieve the next/last value based on a condition using LINQ with EF6?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by your query... I think the whole idea of writing `.GroupBy(u => new { u.UserId, u.FirstNameSurname })` is just an artifact of your original SQL query. But EF will already provide your data grouped by users. If the `GroupBy` is still justified, a little more explanation would probably help.

Comment: As long as `User.UserId` is the primary key (read: unique), the `db.User.GroupBy(u => u.UserId)` should always create exactly one group per user, with one group item per group...

Comment: Yes I think you are correct the `GroupBy` is unnecessary, I've posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your query is a bit strange structured. As a quick fix, try casting your selected date to nullable, so `FirstOrDefault` will start returning `null` instead of some default date:

```
.Select(d => (DateTime?)d.Rota.StartDate)
```

On a closer look, I think you don't need to group your data at all, since querying the `DbSet<User>` will already return the `RotaUser` grouped by users.

So I think the following would be your desired query:

```
var model = db.User
    .Where(u => u.OnCall.Value)
    .Select(u => new OnCallSummaryViewModel
    {
        Name = u.FirstNameSurname,
        Days = u.RotaUser.Sum(x => (int?)x.Rota.Days),
        BankHolidays = u.RotaUser.Sum(x => (int?)x.Rota.BankHolidays),
        Next = u.RotaUser
            .Where(r => r.Rota.StartDate >= today)
            .Min(d => (DateTime?)d.Rota.StartDate),
        Last = u.RotaUser
            .Where(r => r.Rota.StartDate <= today)
            .Max(d => (DateTime?)d.Rota.StartDate),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Note, as far as I can see, your current query (in the question) would return the wrong value for `Last`, since you already select the minimum date before applying `Max`:

```
ru.RotaUser
    .Where(r => r.Rota.StartDate <= today)
    .Select(d => d.Rota.StartDate)
    .OrderBy(d => d) // first date will be minimum, not maximum
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks, the casting to nullable types is not required.

Comment: @mheptinstall really? I think you still need the nullable cast for the cases where every `StartDate` is above/below the current date, so your filtered dates will be empty for Next or Last. Otherwise you don't get a null there.

Comment: No errors reported when there is no data for a user or anything scheduled above/below the current date :)

Comment: Linq to entities never ceases to confuse me... you are right, in contrast to the code contract, it is assigning null.

Comment: @grek40 Yeah, that's exactly what I thought when first saw the question, and which basically is the right way to write L2E queries. I just don't like the translation (too many table access and joins), but probably I'm too maximalist :) +1

Answer (score 1):

In general, to get similar results to SQL queries (where the `NULL` is supported naturally even for columns which are not nullable) with EF query, you should promote the non nullable types (like your `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Days` and `BankHolidays`) to their corresponding nullable type.

But the SQL translation of your LINQ query is terrible. You can try using the direct EF query equivalent of your SQL query:

```
var query =
    from u in db.User
    from ru in u.RotaUser.DefaultIfEmpty() // left outer join
    let r = ru.Rota
    where u.OnCall == true
    group r by new { u.UserId, u.FirstNameSurname } into g
    select new OnCallSummaryViewModel
    {
        Name = g.Key.FirstNameSurname,
        Days = g.Sum(r => (int?)r.Days),
        BankHolidays = g.Sum(r => (int?)r.BankHolidays),
        Next = g.Min(r => r.StartDate >= today ? (DateTime?)r.StartDate : null),
        Last = g.Min(r => r.StartDate <= today ? (DateTime?)r.StartDate : null),
    };
```

Unfortunately this also doesn't get the optimal SQL translation. You can get the desired result by helping out EF query translator with intermediate `let` statements:

```
var query =
    from u in db.User
    from ru in u.RotaUser.DefaultIfEmpty()
    let r = ru.Rota
    where u.OnCall == true
    let ri = new // the expressions needed by group aggregates
    {
        Days = (int?)r.Days,
        BankHolidays = (int?)r.BankHolidays,
        Next = r.StartDate >= today ? r.StartDate : (DateTime?)null,
        Last = r.StartDate <= today ? r.StartDate : (DateTime?)null
    }
    group ri by new { u.UserId, u.FirstNameSurname } into g
    select new OnCallSummaryViewModel
    {
        Name = g.Key.FirstNameSurname,
        Days = g.Sum(r => r.Days),
        BankHolidays = g.Sum(r => r.BankHolidays),
        Next = g.Min(r => r.Next),
        Last = g.Max(r => r.Last),
    };
```

which produces the desired result with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [UserId],
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [FirstNameSurname],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy1].[A3] AS [C3],
    [GroupBy1].[A4] AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1],
        [Filter1].[K2] AS [K2],
        SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1],
        SUM([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2],
        MIN([Filter1].[A3]) AS [A3],
        MAX([Filter1].[A4]) AS [A4]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [K1],
            [Extent1].[FirstNameSurname] AS [K2],
            [Extent3].[Days] AS [A1],
            [Extent3].[BankHolidays] AS [A2],
            CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[StartDate] >= @p__linq__0) THEN  CAST( [Extent3].[StartDate] AS datetime2) END AS [A3],
            CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[StartDate] <= @p__linq__1) THEN  CAST( [Extent3].[StartDate] AS datetime2) END AS [A4]
            FROM   [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[RotaUser] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Rota] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[RotaId] = [Extent3].[RotaId]
            WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[OnCall]
        )  AS [Filter1]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```